# How to change background and textcolor of ErrorDialog of Edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

```
EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEditView);
if (edittext .getText().toString().isEmpty())
edittext.setError("Fill detail");
```

If the value is empty it shows error dialog but as the background is white and the textcolor is also white the error is not visible.

How can I change the color of the background and textcolor??

Answer (score 0):

You can use following piece of code to change the textcolor of error text:

```
edittext.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Fill Detail</font>"));
```